# I am looking at a website called beoplay.com and want to know what jquery plugin is used on a particular page

Tags: jquery, plugins

www.beoplay.com/landingpages/beoplayh4

This is the link. It's a horizontal page slider but how is it done? Is it a plugin or it's custom developed by their developers?

Comment: In your web browser you can do "Inspect Element" and just go to network / resources to see what has been loaded. Try to look at the classes of the element etc to get the name of the plugin.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

All files on the website listed are minified or obfuscated.  However, most of there scripts did have headings, so I managed to grab 6/7 scripts' names.

- MicrosoftAjax.js
- MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js
- **https://greensock.com/** - JavaScript animation library.
- jQuery v1.8.3
- One of them, the word `buy` occurs 415 times, so it's safe to say that one has something to do with purchasing, and not the animation.
- One has a series of extensions blended in: isMobile.js, Bowser - a browser detector (https://github.com/ded/bowser), the buffer module from node.js (http://feross.org), FastClick: polyfill to remove click delays on browsers with touch UIs, http://hammerjs.github.io/
- The last one had a bunch of random stuff in it, like modifying styles.  I suspect this was the one, non-library file they used to code the website.

To answer your question, I'm pretty sure they are using [GreenSock](https://greensock.com) for the image animation.